# How to use PostgreSQL query for rails validation of an address. Depending if the address falls within an saved database of areas

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis

I currently am trying to accept or reject an address for delivery, depending if the address falls in a certain delivery area. 
So I currently have one database that can save the latitude and longitude given an address.But the lat/long is only generated after the address is saved through CRUD ([1.form of the address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2yd4.png)[| 2. Screenshot of latitude and longitude generated after hitting create or update on address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBw6R.png)[| 3. What the database for address looks like in PostgreSQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtNIf.png)). I also have another database that is storing an polygon shaped by four points(these polygons are my database of delivery areas) [4. Screenshot of what the database for stored polygons(delivery areas) looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czOTM.png). I am using PostgreSQL to save the polygon into my database, and also plan on using the geometric operators here for my validation https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/functions-geometry.html

```
select (polygon'((x1,y1),(x2,y2)(x3,y3)(x4,y4))' @> point'(x1,y1)')
```

The query above will return a true if the point falls within the polygon and false if it does not. My questions are 1. How would I get the latitude and longitude to use as a point for the query from the address, as the address is being validated, because as of now, it is only generated after I click create or update. 2.How would I automatically run the query above to test the point against each saved polygon in the database, when i press Create or Update (CRUD) for a new address, and accept the address if it returns a true and reject if it returns a false.

Update: What my model validation looks like for place.rb and its migration table

```
class Place < ApplicationRecord

    geocoded_by :address
    after_validation :geocode, if: :address_changed?

    validates :name, presence: true 
    validates :address, presence: true 

end
```

```
class CreatePlaces < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :places do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :address
      t.float :latitude
      t.float :longitude

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What do you mean by `But the lat/long is only generated after the address is saved through CRUD`? Are you wondering how to lookup the lat/long from the table?

Comment: Hey Matt, I have provided some image links to hopefully make my question more clear on the latitude and longitude. The lat/long is retrieved from an google API after hitting create or update on a new address, but I want to use that lat/long as a point for validation in the query. I'm wondering is there a way to get the lat/long and run the query for a true or false to either accept or reject the address before it is stored into the database of addresses for delivery. Sorry for the question not initially being clear. I hope the images help a bit

Comment: Hey @Tommy, So you mentioned that the lat/long are generated after the save happens, are you doing this through an `after_save` callback? If not could you please share how that is achieved? And if you are using the `after_save` callback what do you think about changing it to use `before_save` so that you have the lat/long values available before the actual save happens.

Comment: hey @Matt, yeah sure, using `before_save` sounds like a possible solution to solving the problem. What would the `before_save` callback look like in this case, and would the PostgreSQL query also be included in my model validation? for determining if the address is within the delivery zone or not